Issue with CurrentTenant.Id Returning Null in BookStore-Angular-FramworkCore Project
I'm currently working on the BookStore-Angular-MongoDb sample project. I'm trying to implement tenant functionality, but I'm encountering an issue with CurrentTenant.Id. Specifically, CurrentTenant.Id is returning null in my setup.
Additional Information:

Do I need to configure anything specific in the project to ensure that CurrentTenant.Id is populated correctly?
How can I add the tenant ID to the token?
Below is an example of the current token I'm using:

{
  "sub": "a966ae1c-ef07-d11b-69e7-3a12ed60a87c",
  "unique_name": "user",
  "preferred_username": "user",
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "email_verified": "False",
  "phone_number_verified": "False",
  "oi_prst": "BookStore_App",
  "client_id": "BookStore_App",
  "oi_tkn_id": "30ddcebc-d29c-b33e-03e4-3a12ed6456f6",
  "jti": "cfc15f79-d8ba-4101-a9e0-24c3dbf5e479",
  "iss": "https://localhost:44367/",
  "exp": 1717373398,
  "iat": 1717369798
}

Version:
Framework: .NET 8
User Interface: Angular
Database Provider: EF Core (Default)
Tiered or separate authentication server: None (Default)
Operating System: Windows (Default)
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples on how to properly configure the project to use CurrentTenant.Id and how to include the tenant ID in the token.
Please check this link can find zip project:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19966
Reproduction Steps

Cloned the repository and followed the setup instructions.
Verified that the project is running correctly without tenant-specific code.
Attempted to use CurrentTenant.Id, but it returned null.
Expected behavior
CurrentTenant.Id should return the tenant ID.

Actual Behavior
CurrentTenant.Id is returning null.
I have created users who belong to a tenant and have manually added tenants in the database. However, I'm not sure how to add the tenant ID to the claims. Could you provide guidance on how to include the tenant ID in the claims for these users?

Your posted claims ("token") does not seem to include a tenant identifier.

@Dai Thank you for your response. I understand that the current token does not include a tenant identifier. This is exactly the issue I'm trying to resolve.
I need guidance on how to include the tenant ID in the token.

You need to show us your code where you're building the set of Claims to the JWT token factory, or whatever the equivalent is in ABP.

please check comment in this link https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19966

None of the screenshots you posted to that GitHub issue show you passing any claims around anywhere...

how to add the tenant ID to the claims

Use AbpUserClaimsPrincipalFactory.
